# Read gradle script and find the tasks defined in it

Tags: gradle

I have a requirement where a gradle script (or gradle plugin) has to parse a gradle file and print all tasks of certain type; I tried referring the gradle tooling api, but did not succeed.

Here is what I tried :

```
ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector().forProjectDirectory(new File(System.env.REPO_ROOT)).connect()
try {
    BuildEnvironment environment = connection.model(BuildEnvironment.class).get()
    connection.model(GradleProject.class).get().getTasks().each {
        if (it instanceof EMTest) {
            println it
        }
    }
} finally {
    connection.close()
}
```

This prints the list of tasks in my current build.gradle, which is expected because nowhere I specified the target gradle file.

When I tried to run (and not print/find tasks in it) with below code. It works.

```
ProjectConnection connection = GradleConnector.newConnector().forProjectDirectory(new File(System.env.REPO_ROOT)).connect()
try {
    BuildEnvironment environment = connection.model(BuildEnvironment.class).get()
    def build = connection.newBuild()
    /* This is where the gradle script location is provided */
    build.withArguments("--continue", "-b", System.env.REPO_ROOT + "/tests/suites/${project.lrgs}.gradle",
            "-PlrgName=${project.lrgs}", "-PlrgMetadataLoc=${lrgMetadataLoc}")
    build.forTasks(project.lrgs)
    build.setStandardOutput(System.out)
    build.run()
} finally {
    connection.close()
}
```

I checked the gradle tooling api but no success. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The tooling API allows external tools (e.g. IDEs) to interact with a Gradle build. A Gradle build script or plugin can just iterate over `project.tasks`.

Comment: Agree when it is within same gradle file. My requirement is something like:
Run: gradle runSuite -PtestScriptFile=foo

This will run runSuite task in build.gradle; But runSuite will have to run all tasks of type MyTest in 'foo.gradle' (as provided by project property). 

MyTest is custom test task type to run perl scripts/shell scripts, defined in a custom gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just maybe using GradleBuild will work? From http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html and **60.4. Running another Gradle build from a build**

In your case something along the lines of

```
task othertasks(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'other.gradle'
    tasks = ['tasks']
}
```

Comment: This will print all tasks of other.gradle. My requirement is to query the tasks of certain type from other.gradle and print/ run them.

Comment: Could you create a spesific task for that

Comment: Actually, that is how my current other.gradle is structured. For example if it has two tasks of type EMTest, then there is another task which simply marks dependsOn for these to task.
And then from my build.gradle I run this specific task of other.gradle

But I'm trying to see if gradle provides a way to read other.gradle and query the tasks of type EMTest so that the additional special task is not required.

Comment: Throwing in a dependsOn I guess will have to manipulate the DAG in some way. At afterEvaluate or something, but that won't be able to run a GradleBuild beforehand, so I don't know how to do it. Have you considered importing the other.gradle? Like apply from: file("$rootDir/../otherproject/build.gradle")

Comment: Guess you're in a whole world of pain with that last suggestion also :)

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question and didn't find an answer in the source code.

But adding the parameter `--console=verbose` when executing a task prints all its subtasks.

```sh
./gradlew :app:installRelease --console=verbose

> Configure project :app
  ...

> Task :app:generatePackageList
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preReleaseBuild
> Task :app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:copyReleaseExpoManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:copyReleaseBundledJs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:installRelease
> Task :app:installRelease SUCCESS
```